# How to get the owner control of a ListViewItemCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, listview

In `C#` or `VB.NET` I would like to retrieve the Listview control that owns a `ListViewItemCollection` that I pass to a function, to be able to do something like this:

```
Private Sub MySub(ByVal Items As ListView.ListViewItemCollection)

    ' Suspend the layout on the Listview Control that owns the Items collection.
    Items.SourceControl.SuspendLayout()

    Do something with the Items collection...

    ' Resume the layout on the Listview Control that owns the Items collection.
    Items.SourceControl.ResumeLayout()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to try to create a new LVI collection, you'd have to specify the LV control which owns it:

```
Dim lviCol As new ListViewItemCollection(myListView)
```

But the collection does not expose the owner even as a Readonly property.  Instead, after an LVI is added to the LV (`myListView.Items.Add(newLVI)`) the owner becomes available via the `ListViewitem.ListView` property:

```
Dim theParent As ListView = Items(0).ListView
```

It doesnt show in Object Browser under the Items collection, but under LVI.  Of course if the LVI Coll has no items that bombs!

Note also, that the `ListViewItem.ListView` property can be Nothing.  When you create an LVI, it is nothing until you add it.  Likewise if you have a reference to an LVI and remove it from the collection, it becomes nothing:

```
Dim lvi As ListViewItem = myLV.Items(n)
myLV.Items.RemoveAt(n)

' lvi.ListView is now Nothing, and .Index is -1, so if you need those prop
' values, save them before you remove.
```